# how to monitor battery usage in android apps per activity?

Tags: android, monitoring, battery, usage-statistics

I want to monitor battery usage on a very granular level. Like what is the battery usage of each individual activity, or even more granular detail like what is the battery usage in running a for loop of my app. Is there any android app or developer tool using which I can do that on an app whose code I already have?

Answer (score 1):

No, because your phone is not capable of measuring "battery usage on a very granular level".

The closest you will get is with a Qualcomm MDP device and [their battery measurement software](https://developer.qualcomm.com/trepn-profiler). Even then, the battery usage by *process* is somewhat guesswork, as the contributors to power drain (CPU, screen, radios, etc.) are shared by all running processes that use them. [A few other off-the-shelf devices may also work](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdn-forums/increase-app-performance/trepn-profiler/28349) as well, though I suspect that the battery measurement software will work a lot better on an MDP, as it has dedicated hardware for this stuff.

Getting finer-grained detail than that will be impractical. At best, with a lot of testing, you might be able to draw some conclusions comparing two algorithms, but for most such algorithms, you would probably be just as well off measuring how much CPU time they took, and extrapolate battery usage from there.

Comment: Seconded. Unless you are measuring exclusively compute bound processes, the very act of trying to measure power will prevent power saving modes from kicking in. This will make your conclusions useless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to use algorithms that are very efficient to minimize power usage by your program. If this is true, you are going about it the wrong way. The power consumption by computational algorithms is trivial compared to (a) the usage of external peripherals such as blue tooth and wireless, and (b) preventing the processor from dropping into an idle state. To maximize the power efficiency of your app, you want it to be idle (meaning asleep, not spinning) for as long as possible.